# How to fix polygons occupying the same space

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm very new to Blender, coming from Lightwave and Modo. I have a hard time solving an issue, that I came across several times. It's multiple faces created in the same space and sharing vertex. I can't even select them as you will see in the video. And even then, how can i solve the problem.
Here is the video showing the issue:

https://youtu.be/K7_GI7R9Sn0

Thank you very much.

Comment: the video is tagged as private.

Comment: Sorry, It's fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your problem, just select all vertices pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then select "Mesh" -> "Merge" -> "By Distance" as in the image.

[image]

If you need you can then adjust the threshold in the redo panel.

[image]

Comment: I've done that before posting but obviously I handled the tool badly because It seems to work fine now. Problem solved, yes. Merging also gets rid of double faces.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!